# Smart card reader not dedected - PCSC Error - 0x8010002e

Tags: pcsc, winscard

My system was working fine but now my any application is not detecting the smart card reader ( SCM Microsystem) attached in the system while it is displaying in device manager.

Here I tried to get the exact error with trying C++ code (winscard.h) to connect the reader,

```
 reader_status = SCardListReadersA(hContext, NULL,(LPSTR) &szReaders, &dwReadersSz);
```

and here it is giving error - 0x8010002e

Is there any advice here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was happening because of wrong registry values.I thought to share my work for other one. What I tried is :-

1. Right-click on the key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais and select Permissions...
2. Click Add.
3. Click Advanced.
4. Click Locations.
5. Click on the computername and click OK.
6. In the window 'Select user or groups', click on Find now.
7. Select LOCAL SERVICE.
8. Click OK.
9. In the window 'Select user or groups', click on OK.
10. In the window 'Permissions for Calais', click on LOCAL SERVICE and make sure 'Full control' , 'Read' and 'special permissions' is allowed.

restart the system and it worked.

found solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e111144e-377c-4bab-b96d-118f7023c0a8/smart-card-application?forum=windowscompatibility)